# Google+ in ShareThis module

Tags: social-network

How can I add the Google+ option in the [ShareThis](http://drupal.org/project/sharethis) module? They posted a [blogpost](http://blog.sharethis.com/2011/07/06/google-1-and-facebook-like-for-sharethis/) on the 6th of July where they stated the Google+ and Facebook options are added to the module. But when I download the module, there is no such thing as a Google+ button...

However they say it's easy to implement, I didn't find any way how to do this. So if anyone would like to help me out here, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: hello dear buddy -  thy for raising this question. I am also interested in this issue. Hopefully someone speaks up and can offer some help. Gretings

Comment: btw, there are lots of other similar modules (AddThis, Servicelinks, etc) plus you can always add a G+ directly with the Google embed code.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use ShareThis with both Google+ and Facebook Like.

Go to Menu>Configuration>Web Services>ShareThis

- Go to *Choose services* to pick Google Plus One or Facebook

or

- Go to *Extra services* to pick Google Plus One or Facebook Like

You can also see details how to set this up directly in the html code [here](http://help.sharethis.com/customization/using-facebook-like-and-google-plusone).